# htaccess to short my urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert my URL

from

```
accounts.php?cat=cr7-stability&subcat=cr7-atonic-gold-trading
```

to

```
accounts/cr7-stability/subcat=cr7-atonic-gold-trading
```

I created htaccess file with code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ accounts.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L]
```

but when I test I'm getting the old url with no changes

PS. I'm testing with online server at a sub domain 
http://cr7.hostato.com/accounts.php?cat=cr7-stability&subcat=cr7-atonic-gold-trading

Comment: Try clearing  your cache.

Comment: i did and i checked on different browser

Comment: What happens when you type the new url in your browser? Does your Rule rewrite it?

Comment: when i type the new url its 404

Comment: what uri are you testing?

Comment: Your url **/accounts/foo/bar** is working fine and there is no 404 I just tested your site. So where is the problem now.?

Comment: http://cr7.hostato.com/fo/bar gives page not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^accounts/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$  accounts.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed there ! maybe it takes time to make effect ?

Comment: set link <a href="accounts/cat/subcat">title</a>